# I debug a dll file with Visual Studio 2015 and load the pdb file, but Visual Studio prompt cannot find the cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll, pdb-files

I downloaded a release version of the asp system from the Internet. I tried to debug with Visual Studio 2015. The system referenced a dll file. The bin directory has a pdb file corresponding to the dll file, but Visual Studio prompt cannot find the source. May I ask which master can help me? Or give me some advice?

To put it another way, I want to track the code logic in the dll file instead of turning off the prompt for Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried this? At runtime open the menu Debug > Windows > Modules. Find the dll you have referenced, there will be a column that indicates is the symbols have been loaded. If it says 'No' right click and select Load Symbols. After that you should be able to set a breakpoint in your code and step into the referenced assembly.

Comment: Do you have the source (cs) file?

Comment: @KlausGütter  No, I only have dll files and pdb files.

Comment: You can only debug in assembly language without source.  The pdb file is used for debugging and links the executable to the source file.  There are tools that will take an executable and make source code but it is very difficult to debug without the real source file.

Comment: @NickHenry  Yes, I have confirmed that visual studio loads the pdb file. But when debugging, I can't step into the referenced assembly. It's very elusive...

Comment: @jdweng  Ah, I understand. I thought that if I had a pdb file, then I could step into the reference file. In your opinion, this can only debug the disassembly language, then I made a wrong assumption. Thank you

Comment: interesting, @tomByTheSea, I've never had an issue doing it this way, I think the difference may be that I use a decompiler in VS (dotPeek, but it would probably work similarly with another decompiler)